# survey::svytotal and estimates based on the entire sample

Tags: r, statistics, survey

I Was checking the script in Bilder's book at http://www.chrisbilder.com/categorical/Chapter6/SurveySmoke.R and came across the following script to calculate a weighted count for cigarette smoking using svytotal:

> svytotal(x = ~ sm_cigs, design = jdesign)

This sounds very straightforward, but how would I generate a total count estimate for the entire sample rather than just the group of smokers? This is probably obvious but I've failed at every attempt.

thanks

Comment: `jdesign <- update( jdesign , one = 1 ) ; svytotal( ~ one , jdesign )`

Answer (score 1):

sorry, the answer should have been obvious and I missed it - to get the total population size you simply do

> summary(jdesign)

or

> survey::svytotal(c(rep(1, nrow(data))), jdesign)

where data is the data object